# Error compiling Box2D on Mac OS : EGL identifiers not found

Tags: c++, macos, box2d

Trying to make / link the Box2D library for a c++ SFML project I'm working on.

Here's what I've done:
Download a fresh Box2D source from github (https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D)

`cd Box2D-master/Box2D/Build`

`cmake ..`

`make`

it gets partway through, then when it reaches

`[ 68%] Building C object glfw/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.o`

it spits out a bunch of errors such as

`/Users/wstone/Documents/Box2D-master/Box2D/glfw/egl_context.c:53:35: error: unknown type name 'EGLint'; did you mean 'GLint'?
static const char* getErrorString(EGLint error)
                                  ^~~~~~
                                  GLint
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gltypes.h:15:18: note: 'GLint' declared here
typedef int32_t  GLint;
                 ^
/Users/wstone/Documents/Box2D-master/Box2D/glfw/egl_context.c:57:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EGL_SUCCESS'
        case EGL_SUCCESS:
             ^
/Users/wstone/Documents/Box2D-master/Box2D/glfw/egl_context.c:59:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED'`

Anyone have any insights? I installed cmake with `brew install cmake`, if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue ,Box2d Master is not having a stable build, try using the release build from the below link

https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/releases